# Google AutoML Video Intelligence Tools?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, video-intelligence-api

I'm using AutoML Video Intelligence and it's very tedious and I was wondering if there was an easier way to create Datasets for the object tracking. An easy way to get the time and position of the box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can find the answers on the mentioned questions reading GCP knowledge base documentation in particular about [AutoML Video Intelligence](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence#two-ways-to-make-your-media-more-discoverable) product.

At least [*Object tracking*](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/object-tracking/docs/index-object-tracking) process is nicely explained in terms of implementation with either [GCP console UI](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/object-tracking/docs/quickstart-console) or constructing [*HTTP calls*](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/object-tracking/docs/quickstart-protocol) to Cloud REST [AutoML API](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/docs/reference/rest).

Furthermore, you can find [example](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/automl/object-tracking/docs/predict#predict_example) tutoring the way how to handle video segments positioning for the relevant prediction requests.

You can adjust initial question, extending it with a certain details about your use case in order to preciously address the solution.